# Android - Up and down navigation buttons on expanding the Search widget

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview, whatsapp, android-search

I am building a chat application just like Whatsapp. I have build the search functionality successfully in my application using the `SearchView` in the `ActionBar`. **This is what I have done so far:**

[image]

Instead of this I want the `SearchView` with navigation up and down arrows (like in Whatsapp) when I click on the search button. **This is what I want to achieve:**

[image]

Here is my code for the Search button:

```
    // SearchView
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();

    searchView.setQueryHint("Search...");

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            adapter.filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {          
            adapter.filter(newText);
            return true;
        }


    });
```

This is the `xml` file in my menu folder:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

     <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/> 

       <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"  
          app:showAsAction="never|collapseActionView"
          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" /> 

</menu>
```

Please tell me how to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: i would suggest you to create a sub class for SearchView say CustomSearchView and try inflating your custom there. And use this class as search view

Comment: @AmrutBidri Can't I do this by using the predefined SearchView?

Comment: Also can you provide any tutorials or examples for CustomSearchView? Thanks